# How can i turn on Developer Mode on ChromeOS launched on VirtualBox?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, google-chrome-os, rootfs, chromium-os

I have launched ChromeOS on VirtualBox. Now I want to turn on Developer Mode to disable the verification of rootfs (root file system). How can I turn on this mode without pressing buttons on laptop, because it`s launched virtually?

Maybe there are some solutions using command line (crosh/shell)

Answer (score 1):

If you can run "shell" from crosh, then the system is already in developer mode.

For non-Chrome OS devices, typically developer mode is turned on by adding `cros_debug` to the kernel command line, and the default Chromium OS builds include that automatically.